# How to position elements based off the center of a page?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 HTML elements

```
<h1 id="prev">TITLE1</h1>
<h1 id="curr">TITLE2</h1>
```

I want to position these elements an X amount of pixels away from the centre of the page. For example I would like to to put `TITLE1` 50 px to the left of the center and `TITLE2` 50 px(same amount of space) to the right of the center. As seen below:

```
 TITLE1<---50px--> |  <---50px--> TITLE2
                (centre)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```css
#prev {float: left; margin: 0; width: 50%; text-align: right; margin-left: -50px;}
#curr {float: right; margin: 0; width: 50%; text-align: left; text-indent: 50px;}
```

```html
<h1 id="prev">TITLE1</h1>
<h1 id="curr">TITLE2</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```css
#headers-set{
    text-align:center;
}
#prev{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:50px;
}
#curr{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="headers-set">
  <h1 id="prev">TITLE1</h1><h1 id="curr">TITLE2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: There will be a small space, and it won't be exactly `50px` but will be `50px`+`1em`. `:)` Check it out!

Comment: You can remove it by removing the space in the HTML. `</h1><!-- --><h1>`. If you know what I mean!

Comment: @Prav just figured it out :D

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the "title Elements", you could also use `position absolute; left:50%` - and then a `left-margin` to move one box 50px to the right, and the other `boxWidth+50` to the left:

```
#prev{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:150px;
    background:blue;
}

#curr{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:50px;
    width:150px;
    background:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ordccd40/

---

Absolute approach without fixed width :)

https://jsfiddle.net/ordccd40/1/

```
#prev{
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    margin-right:50px;
    background:blue;
}

#curr{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: What if the `width`s are unknown?

Comment: @PraveenKumar then this does not work. that's why i wrote `if you know`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Added another one :)

Comment: Gosh! Positioning! Bleh. Nice attempt! `;)`

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
#prev,#curr{
  display: inline;
}
#prev{
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
#curr{
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="prev">TITLE1</h1>
  <h1 id="curr">TITLE2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

this way use the least code.
[JSfiddle.](http://jsbin.com/lomune/2/edit?html,css,output)

```
body{
  text-align: center;
}
#prev,#curr{
  display: inline;
}
#prev{
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
#curr{
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: centering the whole body text?

Comment: @dognose It's a short way to do. In actual case, shouldn't style whole body. Then you can add a parent elements on H1.