# CSS adding random whitespace to images?

Tags: html, css

I want to display images so that they appear horizontally on the same line and are both 50px from the centre of the page. When I try to do this they appear on different lines and **if you look closely there is random white space added onto the right of the google image and left of the intel image.** I asked a similar question here: [How to position elements based off the center of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984289/how-to-position-elements-based-off-the-center-of-a-page/30984321#30984321)

My solution:

```
#image{
   padding:100px;
   background:white;
   text-align: center;
}

#google{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:100px;
}
#intel{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gc3b85cv/3/

How do I get rid of the white space and put them both on the same line horizontally while also making sure they're both 50px from the centre of the page (left and right for the respective images).

```
IMAGE1<---50px--> |  <---50px--> IMAGE2

               (centre)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gc3b85cv/9/ There you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vertical alignment

I assume that you want to vertically centre your element as well—although this was not clear in your question (you mentioned "*same line*" but it could also mean same **baseline**).

The fix is simple: use `vertical-align: middle` on your inline-block level images:

```
#image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### White space issue

That is because you are using `display: inline-block`, therefore each node will be treated like inline elements in a way that any whitespace between them will be interpreted as a space character (just like in text, but unlike block level elements).

To resolve this issue, you can use the `font-size: 0` hack on the parent element—however, the main disadvantage is that if you are using relative font sizes in the children elements, like `em` or `%`, they will compute to 0.

```
#image {
   font-size: 0;
   padding:100px;
   background:white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

See demo fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gc3b85cv/10/

Alternatively, you can simply remove all whitespace between elements, although this makes your markup harder to eyeball:

```
<div id="image"><a href="http://www.google.ca"><img id="google" src="http://placehold.it/250x228" alt="google" style="width:250px;height:228px;" /></a><a href="http://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/homepage.html"><img id="intel" src="http://placehold.it/250x100" alt="Intel Logo" style="width:250px;height:100px;" /></a></div>
```

...or if you really want to preserve the indentation, use `<!-- -->` to comment out whitespace between elements:

```
<div id="image"><!--
    --><a href="http://www.google.ca"><img id="google" src="http://placehold.it/250x228" alt="google" style="width:250px;height:228px;" /></a><!--
    --><a href="http://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/homepage.html"><img id="intel" src="http://placehold.it/250x100" alt="Intel Logo" style="width:250px;height:100px;" /></a><!--
--></div>
```

Comment: don't forget `vertical-align: middle` for the second part of OP's question.

Comment: @JosephMarikle OP was not clear what "same line" means—vertically-centered on the same line? Sharing the same baseline?

Comment: Considering the provided example (and the default functionality) is already aligned at the baseline, I assume middle.  It's possible OP meant aligned along the top of the images, but I am inclined to believe that to be unlikely, and it would require the same rule with a different value (i.e. `vertical-align: top`).

Comment: I'm was looking for something similar to the "picture" I drew. Where the 2 elements aligned at the baseline and both 50px from the centre in opposite directions.

Comment: @Jaquacky Thanks for clarifying that. In this case, you wouldn't need to use `vertical-align: middle`, but if you want them to be 50px from the centre, you should use a margin left/right value of 50px instead of 100px: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gc3b85cv/11/

Answer (score 0):

In your html remove the newlines and whitespace between the two image objects. Whitespace is an html character and will be displayed on the page.